# Check if sourced (.bash_profile) command exists

Tags: bash

`k.sh`:

```
if ! [ -x "$(command -v nvm)" ]; then
    echo 'Error: nvm is not installed' >&2
else
    echo 'nvm installed'
fi
```

Terminal:

```
km@Karl ~/dev/cac (master) $ nvm  --version
0.33.2
km@Karl ~/dev/cac (master) $ . k.sh
Error: nvm is not installed
```

I'd like to have bash check if the command exists! NVM is sourced in `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`.

Comment: `if hash nvm 2>/dev/null; then echo exists; else echo does not exist; fi`

Comment: @KamilCuk Works! Care to answer and explain why my code does not work?

Answer (score 2):

`[ -x ]` tests if a file exists and is executable. It will fail if you pass the name of a shell function or alias. There's no real need for the extra check. Simply checking if `command` succeeded is enough.

```
if ! command -v nvm &> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

`hash` is for me the most portable:

```
if hash nvm 2>/dev/null; then echo exists; else echo does not exist; fi
```

Why it does not work? Let's see what you do:

`command -v nvm` # prints nothing and exits with 1
`$(command -v nvm)` # prints nothing and exits with 1
`[ -x "$(command -v nvm)" ]` exit status of command is ignored. Only the string returned by the command matters. So it is executed like this:
`[ -x "" ]` test command exits with status 1, as the file `""` is not an executable (such file does not exists).
`! [ -x "" ]` then you negate the return status, so it returns 0, i.e. true

If you which to use command -v to check if a file exists, check for it's return status, not the string:

```
if command -v nvm 2>/dev/null; then echo exists; else echo does not exist; fi
```

But hash is a bit more portable, better stick to hash.

Comment: How is `hash` more portable than `command`? Both are defined by POSIX.

Comment: After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) i am now convinced in favor of command. The second answer even has `[ -x "$(command -v foo)" ]`, so i'm puzzled right now.

Comment: It's checking something different. With that command, not only does `foo` have to be a command, but it has to be an executable file, not an alias or function or shell built-in.